# Container with most water algorithm issue

Tags: algorithm

> Given n non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an, where each represents
>   a point at coordinate (i, ai). n vertical lines are drawn such that
>   the two endpoints of line i is at (i, ai) and (i, 0). Find two lines,
>   which together with x-axis forms a container, such that the container
>   contains the most water

What I do not understand about this question is how am I supposed to know the y-coordinate value(height) of the n vertical lines.

Comment: It's given in the question: the y-coordinate is `a_i`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of basic reading comprehension, rather than anything programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values you are given are {1,2,3,4,4,1,3}, the vertical lines would be:

```
4|          |  |
3|       |  |  |     |
2|    |  |  |  |     |
1| |  |  |  |  |  |  |
0| -------------------
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

`ai` is the height of the `ith` line, and it's x coordinate is `i`.

Comment: I got confused because they use the same variable 'i' for both the line and the x co-ordinate